# Branch cut of $\sqrt{z^2 + 1}$

Tags: branch-cuts, branch-points

In my studies I've come across the concept of branch cuts, and I'm having a little bit of trouble digesting the topic. 
As I understand it, in this example:

$$f(z) = \sqrt{z^2 + 1} = \sqrt{z + i}\sqrt{z - i}$$

With the substitution $ z + i = r_1e^{i\theta_1} $ and $ z - i = r_2e^{i\theta_2} $

Then:

$$ f = \sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{\frac{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}{2}} $$

The branch points are located at $ z =i $ and $z = -i $. If we define the branch cut to be from $i$ to $-i$ then any contour enclosing one point but not the other will "pick up" a factor of $ e^{i\pi} = -1$, and any contour enclosing both will "pick up" a factor of $ (-1)^2 = 1$.

My question is, how do we define a sensible value to attribute to $\theta$ on each side of the branch cut? Would $$\theta = \begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2},  & \text{for $x \lt 0$} \\
\frac{5\pi}{2} & \text{for $x \ge 0$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
be a sensible choice?

Comment: It is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988828/how-to-find-the-branch-points-and-cut